# "Missing SEI" when generating artifacts with WSGEN

Tags: java, web-services, jaxb, jax-ws, wsgen

I am a beginner in the development of web services. I want to generate artifacts using wsgen.exe.

Here is my code:

```
  package com.calc.ws;

  import javax.jws.WebService;

  @WebService
  public class Calculator {
      public int add(int a, int b) {
          return (a + b);
      }
      public int sub(int a, int b) {
          return (a - b);
      }
  }
```

The problem I'm facing is when I want to generate the artifacts from the command line with this command (one liner):

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\bin\wsgen 
     -cp "c:\users\mico\workspaceSOA\calcWS\src\com.calc.ws.Calculator" 
     -verbose 
     -d "C:\users\mico\classes\"
```

I get this error:

```
Missing SEI.
```

What is causing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wsgen.exe is called in the following way:

```
WSGEN [options] <SEI>
```

It [reads a web **service endpoint implementation** class (SEI)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/wsgen.html) and generates all the required artifacts for web service deployment, and invocation.

In the command line you posted I only see options, you specified no SEI. And from here the message "Missing SEI" (i.e. you didn't provide a mandatory command line argument).

I don't know your exact setup but if I were to have this structure:

```
c:\temp
├───classpath
│   └───com
│       └───calc
│           └───ws
│               └───Calculator.class
└───generated
```

If I run (on one line):

```
wsgen -cp c:\temp\classpath 
      -keep 
      -s c:\temp\generated 
      com.calc.ws.Calculator
```

I will get my classes, but if I run just:

```
wsgen -cp c:\temp\classpath 
      -keep 
      -s c:\temp\generated
```

I will get:

```
Missing SEI
```

Comment: here is my full path to the Calculator.class:      "c:\users\mico\workspaceSOA\calcWS\bin\com.calc.ws.Calculator" and here is my path for generated output: "c:\users\mico\workspaceSOA\calcWS\src\com.calc.ws.jaxws"
Here you have classpath, is this path to the class file or something else? I was running your line but I get error class not found "com.calc.ws.jaxws"

Comment: what can i say about this answer , thanks but Bogdan i dont like this 3663 palindrome .

Comment: @MitjaRogl it's good that it helped you a lot, but why not share your solution? My point is, this is a place to share knowledge, not just to help you when your in need ok?

Comment: I have tried this but still I couldn't generate the artifacts and still the same error is shown can u help me out.

Answer (score 1):

```
The error "Missing SEI" means Service Endpoint Interface is missing. Please create an interface for your service. please refer below code:

Service Interface:
package com;
import javax.jws.WebService;

@WebService
public interface Calculator {
    public int add(int a, int b);
    public int sub(int a, int b);
}

Service Class implementing Service Interface:
package com;

import javax.jws.WebService;

@WebService
public class CalculatorImpl implements Calculator {
    public int add(int a, int b) {
        return (a + b);
    }
    public int sub(int a, int b) {
        return (a - b);
    }
}

Command which i have used is:
>wsgen -cp . com.CalculatorImpl -keep -verbose -d ./stub

Before executing above please make sure that destination folder stub is already created.

Please try and let me know if still you are facing issue in this...
```

Comment: **A service endpoint interface (SEI) is not required when building a JAX-WS endpoint.** The message is just misleading: It refers to the wsgen.exe parameter SEI (service endpoint implementation) and not the service endpoint interface (also abbreviated SEI).

Answer (score 0):

In my case I am migrating from JAX-RPC to JAX-WS and I changed the package name. By changing this I would have to change all the mappings in xml files, like in webservices.xml for example. A simple solution if you get the **"Missing SEI"** error will be to find and delete the **`webservices.xml`** file and you should be good to go with JAX-WS.

Answer (score 0):

For my case. this work.

1. cd {project_path}/bin
2. "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\bin\wsgen" 
    -cp . com.calc.ws.Calculator
    -verbose 
    -d "C:\users\mico\classes\"
3. done.